# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, modulenotfounderror

i installed kivy and kivymd. now i try to use it and it seems like i've never installed any of it.

```
# importing all necessary modules
# like MDApp, MDLabel Screen, MDTextField
# and MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton

# creating Demo Class(base class)
class Demo(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        
        # defining label with all the parameters
        l = MDLabel(text="HI PEOPLE!", halign='center',
                    theme_text_color="Custom",
                    text_color=(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1),
                    font_style='Caption')
        
        # defining Text field with all the parameters
        name = MDTextField(text="Enter name", pos_hint={
                        'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.8},
                        size_hint_x=None, width=100)
        
        # defining Button with all the parameters
        btn = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="Submit", pos_hint={
                                    'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3},
                                    on_release=self.btnfunc)
        # adding widgets to screen
        screen.add_widget(name)
        screen.add_widget(btn)
        screen.add_widget(l)
        # returning the screen
        return screen

    # defining a btnfun() for the button to
    # call when clicked on it
    def btnfunc(self, obj):
        print("button is pressed!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Demo().run()
```

the code above is just a example code which i used to test it
it gives to following error:

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/niekl/OneDrive/Bureaublad/Rad/Nieuwe map/untitled0.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\niekl\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Rad\Nieuwe map\untitled0.py", line 4, in <module>
    from kivymd.app import MDApp

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'
```

[Kivy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWxeH.png)
[KivyMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMUq2.png)
I installed these packages

Comment: Make sure you installed them in the right environment. Are you running it on notebook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to install it again with

```
pip install kivymd
```

if above solution won't work please do:

```
pip install --force-reinstall https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

**Edit:**

Another option:

```
git clone https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git --depth 1
cd KivyMD
pip install .
```

Read more about the installation options on [kivyMD docs](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. Possible reason for the "space" in the folder name: "Nieuwe map". Try copying the project to another folder or renaming the folder to "Nieuwemap"

Comment: Given the question already has an answer which was accepted long ago and OP didn't seem to mention a space, I'd say that this answer is probably not useful and thus not needed.